# Setting property in Segue but in ViewDidLoad returns null

Tags: ios, objective-c

Ok this really makes me headache. I have ViewController (using replace) that I assign its delegate property

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
  if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"spoSelectionDemoPlanSegue"])
  {
    SPOSelectionViewController * vc = [segue destinationViewController];
    vc.delegate = self;
    NSLog(@"spo segue %@", vc.delegate);  //returns current ViewController
  }
}
```

SPOSelectionViewController.h

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) id<SPOInputDelegate> delegate;
```

SPOSelectionViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];
  NSLog(@"delegate didload spo %@", delegate);  //returns (null)
}
```

Somehow it prints null! However there is my other ViewController (using popover) that I try to assign its delegate and it does not `null`. Anyone can give me suggestion?

Comment: running your app on iOS 6?

Comment: Try in the view will appear, probably view did load called before prepare for segue

Comment: Not really. Setter is called before viewdidiload on iOS 7 or later

Comment: I have a button that call the delegate methods but the delegate itself is null

Comment: The delegate should be weak, not assign

Comment: yes but it doesn't fix the problem

Comment: not sure if this helps but try self.delegate or _delegate to access

Comment: nope, I have synthesized my delegate..

Comment: what if you typecast in this line like - SPOSelectionViewController * vc = (SPOSelectionViewController)[segue destinationViewController];

Answer (score 1):

As I expected and this is silly, since the storyboard's segue is to a navigationController, so actually the destinationViewController is the navigationController not `SPOSelectionViewController`.

So I solved it by this way:

```
UINavigationController* navController = segue.destinationViewController;
SPOSelectionViewController * vc = (SPOSelectionViewController*)navController.topViewController;
vc.delegate = self;
```